# Cannot find DeserializeOwned macro?

Tags: rust

Rust can't find `serde::de::DeserializeOwned` in my code but can find `serde::Serialize`. I'm pretty sure they both exist in serde 1.0.104 though:

```
#[derive(serde::Serialize, serde::de::DeserializeOwned, Default, Debug)]
struct Outside {}
```

Error:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `DeserializeOwned` in `de`
 --> src/lib.rs:3:39
  |
1 | #[derive(serde::Serialize, serde::de::DeserializeOwned, Default, Debug)]
  |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `DeserializeOwned` in `de`
```

[Link to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=extern%20crate%20serde%3B%20%2F%2F%201.0.104%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(serde%3A%3ASerialize%2C%20serde%3A%3Ade%3A%3ADeserializeOwned%2C%20Default%2C%20Debug)%5D%0Astruct%20Outside%20%7B%7D%0A%0Amod%20stone%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%23%5Bderive(serde%3A%3ASerialize%2C%20serde%3A%3Ade%3A%3ADeserializeOwned%2C%20Default%2C%20Debug)%5D%0A%20%20%20%20struct%20Inside%20%7B%7D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The automatic implementation of a trait is done through a procedural macro. If you go to the [`serde::Deserialize` documentation page](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.104/serde/trait.Deserialize.html), you'll see this sentence:

> Additionally, Serde provides a procedural macro called `serde_derive` to automatically generate `Deserialize` implementations for structs and enums in your program.

However, there is no procedural macro to implement the [`serde::de::DeserializeOwned`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.104/serde/de/trait.DeserializeOwned.html) trait automatically, that's why your code cannot compile.

---

To know what you can do, you can read the [serde documentation](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html#trait-bounds): it explains that `DeserializeOwned` is a fancy way to use `Deserialize` whatever the lifetime is. You just have to add `#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]` and use the `DeserializeOwned`.