# Rust cw_storage_plus - how do I satisfy Serialize, DeserializeOwned, and Deserialize<'de> in my struct?

Tags: rust, serde, trait-bounds

I'm teachning myself Rust by building a CosmWasm contract.

`Game` is defined by

```rs
use cosmwasm_std::{Addr, Int256};
use schemars::JsonSchema;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Debug, JsonSchema)]
pub struct Game {
    id: u64,
    owner: Addr,
    round: Int256, // as close to infinite number of rounds as I can think of
    status: GameStatus,
    slots: [Slot; 9],
}
```

(`Slot` is another `struct`, and `GameStatus` is an `enum`, all prefixed with their own `#[derive...` macros.)

I have defined a `Map` of `Games` as follows

```rs
use cw_storage_plus::{Item, Map};

pub const GAMES: Item<Map<u64, Game>> = Item::new("games");
```

In my contract's `instantiate` function I have the following

```rs
// game is an instance of a Game
GAMES.save(deps.storage, 0, &game)?;
```

`GAMES.save` shows error

```
the method `save` exists for struct `Item<'static, Map<'static, u64, Game>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
`cw_storage_plus::Map<'_, u64, Game>: Serialize`
`cw_storage_plus::Map<'_, u64, Game>: DeserializeOwned`
`cw_storage_plus::Map<'_, u64, Game>: Deserialize<'de>`
which is required by `cw_storage_plus::Map<'_, u64, Game>: DeserializeOwned`
```

From what I can tell the issue is not with the `Item` or the `Map` but the `Game` `struct`.

I've tried importing `DeserializeOwned` as in

```rs
use serde::de::{DeserializeOwned}
```

but there is no derive mechanism for it so I can't just add it to the derive.

I read at [stackoverflow.com/a/60091762](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60091762) that

> You just have to add `#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]` and use the `DeserializeOwned`.

I feel like I am missing something obvious but I've not been able to work it out.

Comment: Why are you using `Item<Map>` instead of just `Map`?

Comment: following the example in https://book.cosmwasm.com/cross-contract/map-storage.html - I need an Item because it's how I save the state on-chain.

Comment: lol turns out I simply misread the docs.  You are spot on.  Fixed it.  Many thanks.

Comment: "as close to infinite number of rounds as I can think of" u64 is plenty. If you did one round a second, it will take you 42 times the age of the universe to overflow.